# Where can I find the latest Movesense Showcase app source?

Tags: swift, movesense

According to https://www.movesense.com/news/2020/02/movesense-showcase-ios-app-is-now-open-source/ the showcase app source is open source.  But the source code that’s there in the repo is at least couple of versions behind in terms of UI.

Is there an updated repo location for the latest? Our client is looking at the app in AppStore thinking the source code should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the source code in the repository is exactly the same as has been used for generating and compiling the app store version. Could you please make sure you are using the master branch of this repo: https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/ ?

Also, please make sure that you are opening the folder `MovesenseShowcase` in xcode, **not** `IOS-example` (which is the old example app for iOS)

In addition, please make sure you are using Xcode 11 (latest) and following the instructions in readme.md